# Prestashop 1.6.1.15 - Overriding controller issue

Tags: php, controller, overriding, prestashop-1.6, controllers

I have to fix a problem on an existing website. How it is now:

// controllers/front/ParentOrderController.php

```
class ParentOrderControllerCore extends FrontController

{...}
```

// controllers/front/OrderController.php

```
class OrderControllerCore extends ParentOrderController

{...}
```

// override/controllers/front/OrderController.php

```
class OrderControllerCore extends ParentOrderController

{...}
```

---

But it is not working. I tried the following changes:

// controllers/front/OrderController.php

```
class OrderControllerCore extends ParentOrderControllerCore

{...}
```

// override/controllers/front/OrderController.php

```
class OrderController extends OrderControllerCore

{...}
```

---

Still not working.

Prestashop is not taking into account the overriding files.
Nothing is in **cache/class_index.php** after **clearing/deleting**.

I manually modified the file class_index.php with:

```
'OrderController' => 
  array (
    'path' => 'override/controllers/front/OrderController.php',
    'type' => 'class',
    'override' => false,
  ),
```

And it works fine. But after a cache clearing, the problem is still on. Someone can help?

Comment: Little mistake, it is actually:'OrderControllerCore' => 
  array (
    'path' => 'override/controllers/front/OrderController.php',
    'type' => 'class',
    'override' => false,
  ),

Comment: Works fine on default installation when I override with `class OrderController extends OrderControllerCore`.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the code is correct. Actually it was about the performance parameters in prestashop back office. I didn't know about the option "use cache" to enable caching of dynamic pages... my mistake sorry